# Azure blockchain workbench app use structs in configuration

Tags: ethereum, solidity, azure-blockchain-workbench

Im trying to upload a smart contract to azure blockchain workbench. From the beginner tutorials i see a configuration file is needed. From reference document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain-workbench/blockchain-workbench-configuration-overview#type the supported types which doesnt include structs or mappings. This is a challenge because the smart contract im working with has several structs and even mappings defined and used as state variables. Is there a way around this, to specify state variables of these complex types? Dont know if this is a dumb question, just new to the tool.

Answer (score 1):

The States defined in the configuration file are defined as strings, at least, the Name part of the State is a string. Therefore, you need to have a State variable in your Solidity contract that is also of type String, or enum of Strings.

You can definitely have structs or mappings in your contract, just not for the State variable. However, let's say you have information in a struct for each State value. Then you could do a mapping of that State value to the struct, like this.

```
enum StateType { Active, Pending, Terminated }

struct StateInfo {
    uint age;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
}

mapping (string => StateInfo) stateInfos;

var stateInfo = stateInfos[StateType.Active];
```

Would that work for you?